# Why am I getting this error after installing a new theme on my WordPress site?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I installed this theme to a new Wordpress site and now I'm getting this error on my home page:

> Warning: Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare(), called in /home/content/63/10275663/html/wp-content/themes/welcome_inn/library/tfuse_framework/functions/core.php on line 21 and defined in /home/content/63/10275663/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 990

This is theme I installed: http://themefuse.com/wp-themes-shop/welcome-inn/

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

Let's dissect the warning message. Three things to note; first, the function generating the warning (wpdb::prepare), second, where the error occurs (`core.php`) and the line reference. Let's take a look at the documentation for the wpdb class.

Here's the [WPDB class on the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb). Searching through here, you'll see that the `prepare()` method does exactly that - prepares the query. Looking through the documentation, you'll see a very important line.

> Please note: As of 3.5, wpdb::prepare() enforces a minimum of 2
>   arguments.

Ok, there's your error. [Here's a link with more information.](http://make.wordpress.org/core/2012/12/12/php-warning-missing-argument-2-for-wpdb-prepare/)

Without going any further, I can almost guarantee that this theme hasn't been updated for 3.5. My suggestion to you would be to create a child theme and making an adjustment to the file at the line mentioned in the warning message. Going through the link, you'll see that `prepare()` works like `sprintf` so the change should be pretty insignificant. Here's an example:

`$wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = $id" );`

Would turn into:

`$wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = %d", $id );`

That should get you sorted out. Just a reminder, don't edit the plugin files directly. That may break your ability to upgrade the theme in the future.